# Ng-repeat with Angular dropdown menu and Ruby on Rails API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

Sorry if this has been answered before but I couldn't find a relevant answer. I'm new to both Ruby on Rails APIs and Angular so any help would be appreciated.

My API has 2 models. 'Property' model has properties of 'image' and 'price'. 'Place' model has the single property of 'location', and this model is also referenced inside the Property model.

I'm struggling with the syntax to drill down into the data and populate a list of locations on the page to edit property information. In the code below, the image update is working (url as a string) but I can't see data in the dropdown.

```
<form ng-submit="propertiesEdit.update()">
<div>
  <label>Image</label>
  <input type="text" ng-model="propertiesEdit.property.image">
</div>

<div>
  <label>Location</label>
  <select ng-model="propertiesEdit.property.place">
    <option disabled selected value="">Please select</option>
    <option ng-repeat="property in propertiesEdit.property.place" ng-value="{{ place.id }}">{{ propertiesEdit.property.place.location }}</option>
  </select>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: your assigning the value of this `propertiesEdit.property.place` to this `property` and you're accessing each items via this `propertiesEdit.property.place.location`? replace it by `property.location`? have you done that?

Comment: Yeah I tried that but location is inside place so it doesn't work. Thanks anyway.

Comment: It should work actually if `propertiesEdit.property.place` is really an array with the list of objects in which `location` property is in, cause if not, then it will not going to work definitely I suppose. If you want us to help, you should be providing much information for us to closely replicate your issue

Comment: OK, thanks for the feedback. Like I said I'm new to this. What further information do I need to provide?

Comment: post your angular js code and how your data is structured

Answer (score 0):

Change the below line of code

```
  <option ng-repeat="property in propertiesEdit.property.place" ng-value="{{ place.id }}">{{ propertiesEdit.property.place.location }}</option>
```

To

```
  <option ng-repeat="locationProperty in propertiesEdit.property.place" ng-value="{{ place.id }}">{{locationProperty.location }}</option>
```